# Configure Flume with Oracle AQ

Tags: jms, weblogic, flume, oracle-aq

I have a question about configuring `Apache Flume` with `Oracle AQ` using `JMS`.
In order to set `JMS` between `Oracle AQ` and a remote server (`Flume` for instance), do I need to configure `WebLogic` datasource?

Flume throws me an exception that the datasource is not configured. I have read `Oracle` documentation and it says that in order for a 3-rd party server to work with AQ JMS I need WebLogic datasource.

I don't want to work with `WebLogic`, so I want to be sure that I have understand it correctly and there is no other way.

So I want to set a source for flume to receive messages from Oracle AQ, do I have to create a `WebLogic` datasource or can I work directly with the queue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure Flume directly to Oracle AQ as there is JMS interface to Oracle AQ. You can configure Flume to have source JMS queue or topic.